# Finding minimum in array, fortran

Tags: fortran

I need to help my friend. It is simple task. I need to find a smallest element in the array.

```
program TEST
    ! your code goes here
    integer a(5), n, min
    a = (/2, -5, 3, 5, 8/)
    n = 5
    min = a(1)

    !reading from keyboard
    !do i=1,n
     !read*,a(i)
    !end do

    print*, 'array:'
    do i=1,n
     print*,a(i)
    end do

    !print*, 'отладка, поиск минимального:'
    do i=2,n
     if (min .lt. a(i)) then
      min = a(i)
      !print*, min, a(i), ' '
     end if
    end do

    print*, 'minimal: '
    print*, min

    stop
end
```

So. I don't have problem with alghoritm at all. It is easy for me to do it on any other language)) but not there. Problem appears when I compare `min` and `a(i)`.

Programm thinks that `min < a(i)` all time. Why? So `min` would be `8`, because `8` is the last.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to find the smallest `a(i)` so your test for the minimum so far is the wrong way around: use `if (a(i).lt.min) min=a(i)` or instead.

But you may want to consider `MINVAL(a)`.

Comment: I think it was because spaces and wrong order of variable there : `if (min .lt . a(i))`. I thought its equal `min < a(i)`. About 2nd. I had found it already, so I deleted 2nd part.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav `min .lt. a(i)` is the same as `min < a(i)`, or do I misunderstand your comment?  I'll delete my `exit` part, as it didn't fit, anyway.

Comment: Forget) Its okay now, my fail. I misunderstood something.